# Конфликт 404 ошибки и ЧПУ (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, чпу, http-status-code-404

Файл htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?menu=$1 [QSA,L]
```

При настройке ЧПУ перестает работать 404 ошибка, все не верные URL ведут на главную страницу сайта. Я понимаю что ошибка в настройке работы модуля mod_rewrite, нужна ваша помощь.

Comment: Вам нужно сделать исключение через rewritecond, как с файлами и директориями.

Comment: буду благодарен за пример

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(404error)/$